# Get Response in Another class from Json to Apex

Tags: apex, json

I have integrated one API and I am getting response in one variable string by 
Class A.apxc

```
String response = res.getBody();
```

I have one parser class of the response

```
public class GetTransactionContainer{   
    public cls_transaction[] transactions;    
    class cls_transaction {        
        public String CONTAINER;
        public Integer id;  
        public String type;  
        public String subType;  
        public cls_amount amount;
        public String baseType;  
        public String categoryType; 
        public Integer categoryId; 
        public String category;  
        public String categorySource; 
        public cls_description description;
        //public String date;  
        public String postDate;  
        public String transactionDate; 
        public boolean isManual;
        public String status;  
        public Integer accountId;  
        public cls_runningBalance runningBalance;
        public String checkNumber;  
        public Integer highLevelCategoryId;  
    }
    class cls_amount {
        public Integer amount;  
        public String currencyAmount;  
    }
    class cls_description {
        public String original;
        public String simple;  
    }
    class cls_runningBalance {
        public Integer amount;  
        public String currencyAmount;  
    }
    public Static GetTransactionContainer parse(String json){

        return (GetTransactionContainer) System.JSON.deserialize(json,GetTransactionContainer.class);
    }    
}
```

I want to get the values from GetTransactionContainer class and put it into Object Named Transaction__c.
Whenever I am trying to do

```
GetTransactionContainer getTxn = GetTransactionContainer.parse(response);
```

I am not getting anything in getTxn even if there is response in "response" variable. 
I would be thankful if anybody can help me on this. Not sure if I am doing something wrong or missing?

Sample Response

```
{
    "transaction": [
        {
            "CONTAINER": "bank",
            "id": 25335410,
            "type": "OTHER_DEPOSITS",
            "subType": "CREDIT",
            "amount": {
                "amount": 3465,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "baseType": "CREDIT",
            "categoryType": "INCOME",
            "categoryId": 32,
            "category": "Other Income",
            "categorySource": "SYSTEM",
            "description": {
                "original": "DESC",
                "simple": "DESC"
            },
            "date": "2017-03-16",
            "postDate": "2017-03-16",
            "transactionDate": "2017-03-16",
            "isManual": false,
            "status": "POSTED",
            "accountId": 10563602,
            "runningBalance": {
                "amount": 59,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "checkNumber": "DAG-133",
            "highLevelCategoryId": 10000012
        },
        {
            "CONTAINER": "bank",
            "id": 25335412,
            "type": "OTHER_WITHDRAWALS",
            "subType": "DEBIT",
            "amount": {
                "amount": 3103,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "baseType": "DEBIT",
            "categoryType": "EXPENSE",
            "categoryId": 19,
            "category": "Other Expenses",
            "categorySource": "SYSTEM",
            "description": {
                "original": "DESC",
                "simple": "DESC"
            },
            "date": "2017-03-14",
            "postDate": "2017-03-14",
            "transactionDate": "2017-03-12",
            "isManual": false,
            "status": "POSTED",
            "accountId": 10563602,
            "runningBalance": {
                "amount": 59,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "checkNumber": "DAG-333",
            "highLevelCategoryId": 10000009
        },
        {
            "CONTAINER": "bank",
            "id": 25335411,
            "type": "OTHER_DEPOSITS",
            "subType": "CREDIT",
            "amount": {
                "amount": 5646,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "baseType": "CREDIT",
            "categoryType": "INCOME",
            "categoryId": 32,
            "category": "Other Income",
            "categorySource": "SYSTEM",
            "description": {
                "original": "DESC",
                "simple": "DESC"
            },
            "date": "2017-03-10",
            "postDate": "2017-03-10",
            "transactionDate": "2017-03-11",
            "isManual": false,
            "status": "POSTED",
            "accountId": 10563602,
            "runningBalance": {
                "amount": 59,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "checkNumber": "DAG-233",
            "highLevelCategoryId": 10000012
        },
        {
            "CONTAINER": "bank",
            "id": 25335413,
            "type": "OTHER_DEPOSITS",
            "subType": "CREDIT",
            "amount": {
                "amount": 9846,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "baseType": "CREDIT",
            "categoryType": "INCOME",
            "categoryId": 32,
            "category": "Other Income",
            "categorySource": "SYSTEM",
            "description": {
                "original": "DESC",
                "simple": "DESC"
            },
            "date": "2017-03-02",
            "postDate": "2017-03-02",
            "transactionDate": "2017-03-16",
            "isManual": false,
            "status": "POSTED",
            "accountId": 10563602,
            "runningBalance": {
                "amount": 59,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "checkNumber": "DAG-333",
            "highLevelCategoryId": 10000012
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you post JSON returned?

Comment: Check that the JSON text in the `response` variable matches the class. For example does the JSON start with `{"transactions": [...` or `[...`. If it is the latter, you probably need `JSON.deserialize(json,cls_transaction[].class);`. https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ is very helpful for getting the Apex and JSON to match.

Comment: Thanks @KeithC for quick reply let me check the response.

Comment: @kurunve and KeithC posted the sample response body as well in post

Comment: @Sagar The JSON has "transaction" but you've called the field "transactions": change the field name. (Or if you are in control of the JSON generation, using a plural in the JSON reads a bit better so change at that side.) Your existing `JSON.deserialize` call is correct.

Comment: Thanks @KeithC. yes I saw that. I changed the name for transaction as it is keyword.
I edited the response only. now it is working as expected.

Comment: That's good. Go ahead and post that as an answer yourself so people know the problem is solved. (If your reputation points allow you to do that.) Then you can accept that answer in a couple of days.